# Convert string to number value

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

From my C# code-behind I send a string value to my dataset. The data table also contains a field string type, which is dragged and dropped into Crystal Reports.

Now I need to divide that (string) value by some number, but strings can't be divided. So I need to convert the string to a value first - but I can't. No matter how I try to convert it always shows 0 on the report.

---

I created a formula called Euro:

```
NumericText({MYVALUE}) then ToNumber({MYVALUE})
```

And accessed it from another formula, EuroNum:

```
(If NumericText({Total}) then ToNumber ({Total}))
```

Then I created another field lets say TotalEuro where I did this in forumla, but it's always showing 0:

```
Euro/1.95
```

Comment: Why are you storing a number as a string in the database to begin with?

Comment: Is the `Euro` field at least displaying correctly? Or is that displaying `0` too?

Comment: @InBetween well long story, I did not started project from the bottom, and why someone did that I really don't know, I get this project from my friend and now I am trying to solve this, and its really interesting why it does not want to work

Comment: @4444 its displaying 0.00 when I use  `NumericText({MYVALUE}) then ToNumber({MYVALUE})` and I know real value of "MYVALUE" field is not zero

Comment: I see. And does this still happen when you replace `ToNumber(` with `Val(` ?

Comment: You didnt tell where you have placed the formula in report. Also write else every time so that you if IF is working or not

Answer (score 1):

I used this formula:

```
If NumericText({VALUE}) Then ToNumber({VALUE}) / 1.955
```

Everything seems fine with Crystal Reports but I had problem in Visual Studio.
 Even if this file is set up to copy everytime ,file somehow not copy changes to debug folder. So I manually moved this file to debug folder and everything was fine.

Comment: Acctualy I have problems again, its showing me 0,0 when I do this formula : `If NumericText({VALUE}) Then ToNumber({VALUE}) / 1.955`, I really dont know why.. P.S (values) IS STRING TYPE BUT ITS NOT SHOWING ME ANY ERRORS IN FORMULA OR SMTH LIKE THAT, BUT ANYWAY ITS SHOWING 0,0 WHEN I APPLY THAT FORMULA